# Spring bean with no id or name

Tags: spring

I'm reviewing some Spring code, and I see a few bean defs that do not have an id or a name.
The person who did it is not around to ask.
The application is working fine.
I am not familiar what this necessarily means.
Anybody know if this means anything in particular?

Comment: Consider posting an example definition - without seeing the definition in context, it is hard to give a concrete answer.

Comment: If no name is supplied explicitly, the container will generate a unique name for that bean.

Comment: By default, the bean's ID will be generated by camel-casing the class name.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Some beans are not required to be accessed by other beans in the context file or programmatically. So as mentioned by JacobM, they don't require an id or name as they're not referenced.

Such an example would be a [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html), which reads a property file, then allows for runtime property replacement in the context definition.

The example definition would be

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="myapp.properties" />
</bean>
```

The JavaDoc provides further documentation on this object, but further on in the file you can reference properties from your file by just using the standard template replace placeholder ${...}.

Comment: So, when this class will be instantiated ?

Answer (score 8):

One possibility is that you can define a bean in place, and so you don't need an id since you don't need to refer to it from anywhere else.  Say I have a Foo object that takes a Bar property:

```
<bean id="foo" class="Foo">
     <property name="bar">
         <bean class="Bar">
     </property>
</bean>
```

The Bar bean doesn't need a name because it's only used to set that one property.

Answer (score 6):

Check the possibility of auto-wiring. An other bean could reference the unnamed bean by having the autowire property set to byType.

This is just a guess. Without a concrete example, I can't say any more.

Answer (score 3):

The id and name attributes are optional and are used to reference the bean definition from other definitions. Look at the [official Spring documentation](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-beanname) for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-beanname it says,

> You are not required to supply a name or id for a bean. If no name or id is supplied explicitly, the container generates a unique name for that bean. However, if you want to refer to that bean by name, through the use of the ref element or Service Locator style lookup, you must provide a name. **Motivations for not supplying a name are related to using inner beans and autowiring collaborators**.

Also, Beans such as BeanPostProcessor, BeanFactoryPostProcessor and PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer are automatically detected by application context and typically won't have name

If you consider any spring bean, Spring mandates it to have an identifier. In case, if you have not provided any identifier (via id or name attribute) to a bean in your configuration, you won't run into exceptions. Spring will manage such situation by assigning a default identifier. it has BeanNameGenerator to assign default name. `<bean class="com.package.name.TestBean">` will be named as "com.package.name.TestBean" `@Bean` kind of beans will have its method name as bean name

thus, in your code, for some reason, you can skip naming few beans and the code still works if you are accessing those beans with their default name

credits : https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/spring-bean-names.html

Answer (score 1):

Beans without id or name can still be referenced by the class name. Spring names those beans automatically using the class name and if there is more than one bean of the same class it appends a number to them.
Anonymous beans are usually defined inside a property tag, but if they're just there maybe there's autowiring configured in some other beans.
Anyway, I think adding a name or id to those beans won't break your application.

Answer (score 1):

As a couple of people mentioned above, not all bean-grabbing is based on name/ID; some of it is based on type. For example, there is a method

BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(...)

that grabs all the beans of some given type. This is used for example by the Spring Web MVC DispatcherServlet (among many other places) to discover beans by type, such as HandlerMappings, HandlerAdapters, HandlerExceptionResolvers and so forth. Contrast this with cases where the bean must have a specific well-known name/ID to be found, such as the LocaleResolver (ID must be "localeResolver" or it won't be found) and ThemeResolver (ID must be "themeResolver" or it won't be found).

Answer (score 1):

Beans defined without name and ID can be accessed with a generated ID (full package name and class name), for example:

bean defined as

```
<bean class="pl.finsys.initOrder.TestBeanImpl">
```

can be accessed by

```
TestBean bean = (TestBean) ctx.getBean("pl.finsys.initOrder.TestBeanImpl");
```

Answer (score 1):

//Bean Cfg File without Bean id

`<bean class="com.ds.DemoBean">
         <property name="msg" value="Hello"/>
</bean>`

//We can Access

Object obj=factory.getBean("com.ds.DemoBe

Answer (score 0):

its not a mandatory to provide java Bean Id..If we  are not providing Bean Id,our Container Provides the Default Been Id.Default Bean Id look like as 
"(Package Name).(Bean Class Name)#N"where N=0,1,2,......etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a subtle difference between unnamed and named bean behaviour. If you have an XML config file imported twice, each named bean will be created only once, but an unnamed bean will be created as many times as its definition is included. When trying to autowire such a bean by type, it leads to errors like this:

```
No qualifying bean of type [your.class.Name] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 4
```