# Anonymous Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

How is an anonymous Spring bean useful?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322208/spring-bean-with-no-id-or-name

Comment: Names are useful when you are going to reference them (perhaps in a bean property injection reference). If you are searching the spring by type (autowiring by type does this) then names are optional.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two uses that i can think of straight of.

**As an inner bean**

```
<bean id="outer" class="foo.bar.A">
  <property name="myProperty">
    <bean class="foo.bar.B"/>
  </property>
</bean>
```

**As a configurer of static properties**

```
public class ServiceUtils {

      private static Service service;

      private ServiceUtils() {}
      ...

      public static void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
      }
    }

    public class ServiceConfigurer {
      private static Service service;

      private ServiceUtils() {}
      ...

      public void setService(Service service) {
        ServiceUtils.setService(service);
          }
    }
```

Now that class can be configured like this.

```
<bean class="foo.bar.ServiceConfigurer">
    <property name="service" ref="myService"/>
</bean>
```

In addition if there is a bean that is not depended upon by any other bean eg [RmiServiceExporter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/api/org/springframework/remoting/rmi/RmiServiceExporter.html) or MessageListenerContainer then there is no need other than code clarity to give this bean a name.

Answer (score 4):

There is several uses:

- a bean injected inline as dependency in other bean
- a bean that implements InitializingBean and DisposableBean, so his methods are called by IoC container
- a bean implementing BeanClassLoaderAware, BeanFactoryPostProcessor and other call-back interfaces

Comment: Can you explain what is "bean injected inline"?

Comment: See example in mR_fr0g's answer

Answer (score 4):

On top of already provided answers (inner bean, life-managing interfaces, configurer of static properties) I would another one, which we use a lot. That is...

- in combination with autowiring (by type). When you configure multiple objects of given type and you don't really care how they are called in XML.